# VB.NET how to find id from placeholder

Tags: vb.net, placeholder

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUsername" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername" style="width:95%;" class="TextBoxWatermark" autocomplete="off">
```

^^^^^^
html Code

i use ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername for id element but not found !

what is the id element ???

Comment: On server- or on clientside? Where anhow have you tried to find the control?

Comment: How did you use it? Can you post more code?

Comment: Have you tried `var contentPlaceholderId = '<%= Me.ContentPlaceholder1.ClientId %>'` ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter on client i'm try to click element by id.

Comment: @codingbiz i'm use for click to the element by id but i'm not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a master page you can access it like so:

```
Dim MainContent as ContentPlaceHolder = CType( Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent"), ContentPlaceHolder)
 Dim myTextbox as Textbox = Ctype(MainContent.FindControl("txtUsername"),Textbox)
```

Comment: if i'm not admin ,i can assess it ??

Comment: This would be a way to access it in the code-behind for the page.  Where are you trying to access the ID from?

Comment: i'm a client and i'm tried to auto click with id but this id is not found.

Comment: Ok, yeah then what I said isn't going to be much help since you aren't trying to access the control via code.

Comment: how to solved it ?, i want to get element id from placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'focus()' command? Are you just trying to make it the selected field?

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername").focus();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: on the client side: "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername" is your element id. On the server side: "txtUsername" is your id.

Comment: i tried ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername is id in client side
but not found this id ps. i'm tried in .aspx not work but i'm tried in
.html , .php is work

Comment: Perhaps the TextBoxWatermark class is interfering. Try removing it to test? Ajax toolkit sometimes has weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

1. You can inspect the element (e.g. in chrome) to know the generated id
2. `var elem = document.getElementById('<%= ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtUsername").ClientID %>');`